# Using Kaltura VPaaS API, how to get READY status after uploading video?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, kaltura, kaltura-player

Once the video is uploaded, the media status is CONVERTING.
on the KMC dashboard.
after a while, the status would be READY,
How can I check the status?
I mean how to get the status is READY.

Answer (score 1):

Check for it ;-)

Goto https://developer.kaltura.com/console/service/media/action/list

And add a filter:
[image]

Scroll all the way to the bottom to find status:
[image]

Finally...see the "Sample Code" Section, which auto-generates sample code for whatever options you choose in the api console.

In this case, for node.js, it is:

```
let filter = new kaltura.objects.MediaEntryFilter();
filter.statusEqual = kaltura.enums.EntryStatus.READY;
let pager = new kaltura.objects.FilterPager();

kaltura.services.media.listAction(filter, pager)
.execute(client)
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```